# How to create a dashboard in Appdynamics based on specific REST URLs of one endpoint

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, appdynamics

I have a Spring application monitored by Appdynamics. This application has a Service Endpoint recognized by Appdynamics, named lets say: */general/endpoint*

Now within the application there are multiple endpoints like:

- */general/endpoint/do-something-1*
- */general/endpoint/do-something-2*

Now back to Appdynamics: Within the Service Endpoints menu I can find my */general/endpoint* and click on it. Then I see a table with the actual REST API calls, their respective execution time, the specific URL (like */general/endpoint/do-something-1*) and some more information.

If I am interested in monitoring the requests for a specific URL I can do the following:

1. Select Filters
2. Add Criteria > HTTP Request > URL
3. Click on the added Criteria and enter the actual URL (*/general/endpoint/do-something-1*)
4. Apply

Now I see what I want, all the requests and their potential problems for a specific URL inside my application.

Now comes my actual question:

**How can I achieve the same for Dashboards?**

I was only able to create a dashboard with the *Calls per Minute* for the */general/endpoint* but not for a specific URL like */general/endpoint/do-something-1*. Is there a way to apply the more fine grade filter for dashboards as well?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could see to be able to get the ability to cut up your Service Endpoint data within a Custom Dashboard would be to use Analytics with a Custom Schema.

Steps to implement would be:

- Export Service Endpoint Data using API -> https://docs.appdynamics.com/21.9/en/extend-appdynamics/appdynamics-apis/metric-and-snapshot-api
- Import the data into a Custom Analytics Schema -> https://docs.appdynamics.com/21.9/en/analytics/adql-reference/adql-data/analytics-custom-events-data
- Then you will be able to use ADQL queries to write SQL-like queries against the data -> https://docs.appdynamics.com/21.9/en/analytics/adql-reference/adql-queries
- Using these within Analytics Widgets in a Custom Dashboard will then give you what you need -> https://docs.appdynamics.com/21.9/en/analytics/using-analytics-data/visualize-analytics-data

For this you would need Analytics Licensing in addition to your APM licensing.